# Gradle Error in contextLoads under test

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

i am trying to build a web using Spring and Angular Js tegether w/ Gradle. my problem is When i run my project or build gradle this error comes out.
"contextLoads FAILED"

"What went Wrong:"

.> There were failing tests.: /build/reports/tests/test/index.html

Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

ContextLoad Leads me to this Class:

```
package com.linkedin.learning.linkedinlearningfullstackappangularspringboot;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LinkedInLearningFullStackAppAngularSpringBootApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

heres the screenshot to make it clearer: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIbPI.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details about your application? What configuration classes and Spring-managed beans does it contain? The complete error message and stacktrace (available in Gradle's JUnit report) would also be useful.

Comment: Oh ok. this isnt a specific lines of error i am facing. thanks for the idea.